# Button to execute shorcode

Tags: buttons

I have site using elegantthemes DIVI.
I would like to add a button on a page that would execute a short code called [book] which when pressed would execute the short code taking the user to a booking page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does that mean: "execute a shortcode"? Shortcodes return strings when the page is rendered. You don't need a button for that.

Comment: Any reason why you can't have a link to the booking page styled as a button?

Answer (score 1):

That could be have a sense if the shortcode is only for content and if that can help you to limit the charge of queries.

Then use wp_ajax and do_shortcode in.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

But keep careful because a lot of shortcodes define css in wp_head & js in wp_footer, so with this solution it will not work nicely.

Comment: this is an answer with no real content :( just putting some links do not make even a mediocre answer

Answer (score 0):

`add_shortcode('book','myfunc');
function myfunc(){
 return "";
}`

The above code shall display the shortcode with the required button

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 if(jQuery('#mybutton').length!=0){
   jQuery('#mybutton').click(function(){
     window.location='http://www.google.com';
   });
 }
});`

The above code will take the user to google.com when the button is clicked, you need to include this script using the  tag or you can also enqueue the script using the wp_enqueue_scripts tag like this

`function enqueue_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', $path_to_js, array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );`